# Deleting Shapes from Excel worksheets using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a series of macros to clean up worksheets before distributing weekly versions of a file.

One of the tasks is to remove all the control objects for macros.

I have listed specific objects to remove for each sheet so have a handful of lines like the one below.

```
Sheets("Open SO").Shapes.Range(Array("Button 6", "Button 7", "Button 11", "Button 12")).Delete
```

But it is giving me an error and I can't see why.
The runtime error is 1004 with the message (roughly translated) "the specified object can't be found".

The sheet exists (I've tried with both "Sheets" and "Worksheets" but since I'm naming the worksheet there should be no difference). The button names do exist.

I'm running the macro manually from the Developer menu and it's in a module in the same workbook.

Is the syntax wrong?

EDIT

It seems the object names had changed but the change was in the language.

For the first sheet I recorded a macro to get the button names in a form making them easy to copy and paste. The first time I recorded a macro it gave me this code:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 12", "Button 11", "Button 6", "Button 7")). _
Select
Selection.Delete
```

When I checked again today by recording a macro the code was:

```
  ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("ボタン 12", "ボタン 11", "ボタン 6", "ボタン 7")). _
  Select
  Selection.Delete
```

The PC the file was edited on has Japanese Windows and Japanese Office but since English is often under the hood, I didn't think anything about the initial labels being English. Initially the code did work but after tidying it up to a single line it stopped working.

If I change the original line of code to include Japanese labels it does work.

I now have a related but different problem (maybe I should start a new thread). Two people need to use these macros. One of us use Japanese the other English. The Japanese macro works on my machine. Neither the Japanese nor the English work on the other person's machine which runs English Windows and Office (the button names stay in Japanese on the second machine).

I've ended up with the same problem on a different machine.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any problem with the code you've posted.  Is the workbook with the buttons the active workbook when it runs?  `Sheets("Open SO")` looks in the current activeworkbook, `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Open SO")` look in the workbook containing the code.

Comment: Yes, it is the active workbook. In fact it's the only workbook open when I run the macro.

Comment: Have you changed the texts of the buttons or are they still `"Button 6", "Button 7", "Button 11", "Button 12"`?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I had not changed the button names but there was an unexplained change so I've edited my original post.

Comment: Is that all the shapes on the sheet? You could iterate the worksheet's `Shapes` collection and query and delete them from there (perhaps matching the names against a map of En/JP names?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Button Mystery

- When you start adding buttons, their name and text are the same e.g. `Button 1`, `Button 2`... etc.
- Once you start deleting and renaming them and adding new ones, their text and name could (will) end up being different.
- Use the following tool to find out what has happened in your particular case. Your feedback is expected e.g. *"My `Button 6` has miraculously become `Button 13` while its text still remains `Button 6`..."*.

```vb
Sub DeMystifyButtons()
    
    Dim ButtonNames()
    ButtonNames = Array("Button 6", "Button 7", "Button 11", "Button 12")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Open SO")
    
    Dim btn As Button, i As Long, IsFound As Boolean
    
    Debug.Print "Index", "Name", "Text", "Is Found"
    
    For Each btn In ws.Buttons
        IsFound = IsNumeric(Application.Match(btn.Name, ButtonNames, 0))
        Debug.Print btn.Index, btn.Name, btn.Text, IsFound
    Next btn
    
End Sub
```

**Extras: List**

```vb
Sub ListAllButtons(ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    If ws.Buttons.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Debug.Print "Index", "Name", "Text"
    Dim btn As Button
    For Each btn In ws.Buttons
        Debug.Print btn.Index, btn.Name, btn.Text
    Next btn
End Sub
```

**Extras: Delete**

```vb
Sub DeleteAllButtons(ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    ws.Buttons.Delete
End Sub
```

**Extras: Usage**

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Open SO")

    ListAllButtons ws
    'DeleteAllButtons ws
     
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

```vb
Sub DeleteByID()

    Dim ButtonIDs(): ButtonIDs = Array("6", "7", "11", "12")

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Open SO")

    DeleteButtonsByID ws, ButtonIDs
     
End Sub

Sub DeleteButtonsByID(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal ButtonIDs As Variant)
    Dim btn As Button
    For Each btn In ws.Buttons
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(Trim(Right(btn.Name, 2)), ButtonIDs, 0)) _
            Then btn.Delete
    Next btn
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I've edited my original post as there is something odd going on. I had wanted to specify buttons to delete but I may have to change to the generic DeleteAllButtons sub you suggest.

Comment: I decided to go for the Buttons.Delete approach as there were no additional buttons on those particular sheets.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the command is correct. The error means that (at least) one of the shapes doesn't exist. Maybe you have a typo in the name or the shape was already deleted.

Try for example the following routine. It will delete all shapes that you specify, but if a shape doesn't exists (or cannot be deleted for any other reasons), it will just write the shape name to the immediate window and continue the work.

```
Sub DeleteShapes(ws As Worksheet, shapeNames)
    Dim shapeName
    For Each shapeName In shapeNames
        On Error Resume Next
        ws.shapes(shapeName).Delete
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Error when deleting shape '" & shapeName & "': " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
End Sub
```

You could call the routine for example with

```
 DeleteShapes ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Open SO"), _
                Array("Button 6", "Button 7", "Button 11", "Button 12")
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Certainly adding error handling in my macro is needed but it seems at the moment all the names are wrong (have changed) so I'd end up with the macro finishing gracefully having done nothing except display the names. I've edited my original post.

Comment: If you cannot identify the shapes by name, you need to find a different criteria. You could delete *all* shapes, or loop over all shapes and check the number, or check the shape type if you want to delete all buttons.